# How to make div occupy next row in CSS grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a scrollable table with grid on React. My problem is that, when rendering the data, it all goes into the first line. I want it the data to instead occupy the next row in the grid. The grid's rows and columns are rendering just fine, but the data itself renders only in the first row.

CSS:

```
.scroller {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50rem;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    grid-area: scroll-list;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
    /* grid-auto-rows: 50px; */
    grid-template-areas: "test test test";
}

.test {
    grid-area: test;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "name pos ovr";
}

.name {
    grid-area: name;
}

.pos {
    grid-area: pos;
}

.ovr {
    grid-area: ovr;
}
```

HTML:

```
class ScrollList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
 //TODO: I need to make the second row start on the second row!
  render() {
    let count = 0;
    return(
      <div className="scroller">
        {listVals.map((player) => {
          let id = listKeys[count];
          count += 1;
          return(
            <div key={id} className="test">
              <div id={id} className="item name">{player[0]}</div>
              <div className="item pos">{player[1]}</div>
              <div className="item ovr">{player[2]}</div>
            </div>

          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have found a very similar problem here ([css grid can't display data on next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887449/css-grid-cant-display-data-on-next-row)) but the answer doesn't have any upvotes and I am not familiar with table tags (trying to solve this exclusively with grid).

Answer (score 1):

try grid-area: 2;
read this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-area.asp for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment. Looking into this provided a different workaround inspired by the same approach

Comment:  you won the internet for today

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author, to move the solution to the answer space)*.

I figured it out, it was a very simple fix. I had to make the following changes:

```
.scroller { 
grid-template-columns: 1fr
**removed** grid-template-areas: "test test test";
}

.test {
**removed** grid-areas: test;
}
```

Takeaway: don't put rows or columns in a grid-container if you don't have to. Putting 3 columns in my .scroller grid as opposed to three columns in my .test grid was unnecessary since .test grid is the grid using the three columns. This caused the problem.